# unexplainable malloc call in simple test program : malloc project

Tags: c, memory, malloc, dynamic-library, dyld

In a purpose to achieve a school project, I must recode malloc and free functions using only mmap and munmap. I must also compile those functions in a dynamic library (.so file) and use this during the run time.

I am working under mac OS Sierra 10.12.6.

Here is my problem, when I run my very simple program without any malloc call, but using the dynamic library, I can notice some malloc call causing unwanted pages reclaim. The test program I am talking about :

```
int    main()
{
  int i;
  char *addr;
 
  addr = 0;
  i = 0;
  while (i < 1024) {
    i++;
  }
  return (0);
}
```

I am trying to learn how to use debugging tools such as strace, but right now I can notice the malloc call simply using a printf inside my own sources. Indeed, when I run the test, the printf is called while no malloc is used. Here is the commands I am using to compile and run everything :

```
gcc -shared srcs... -o lib_malloc.so
gcc test.c -o test -L ./ -lmalloc
./run.sh ./test
```

(sources files are already compiled as objects files with -Wall -Wextra -Werror flags before linking at the first line)

Here is run.sh file :

```
#!/bin/sh
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="lib_malloc.so"
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
$@
```

I have written a simple memory print function as well. Its purpose is to print every allocated block by my own malloc calling my linked lists and printing it... If I add it to the end of my test.c code, I can see some blocks, like this :

```
TINY : 0x106f65000
0x106f65052 - 0x106f65072 : 4 octets
0x106f6509c - 0x106f650bc : 4 octets
0x106f650e6 - 0x106f65106 : 4 octets
0x106f65130 - 0x106f6513f : 1 octets
0x106f65169 - 0x106f65196 : 5 octets
0x106f651c0 - 0x106f651fa : 7 octets
0x106f65224 - 0x106f65251 : 5 octets
0x106f6527b - 0x106f652ad : 6 octets
0x106f652d7 - 0x106f65306 : 5 octets
0x106f65330 - 0x106f6533e : 1 octets
0x106f65368 - 0x106f653a8 : 8 octets
0x106f653d2 - 0x106f65403 : 6 octets
0x106f6542d - 0x106f65470 : 8 octets
0x106f6549a - 0x106f654ce : 6 octets
0x106f654f8 - 0x106f6552e : 6 octets
0x106f65558 - 0x106f65564 : 1 octets
0x106f6558e - 0x106f655bb : 5 octets
0x106f655e5 - 0x106f6564b : 12 octets
0x106f65675 - 0x106f65685 : 2 octets
0x106f656af - 0x106f656ef : 8 octets
0x106f65719 - 0x106f65727 : 1 octets
0x106f65751 - 0x106f65851 : 32 octets
```

We can notice that only "tiny" unwanted spaces have been allocated anyway ...
I might have done a stupid error somewhere or misunderstand something , if someone understand what's happening, it will rescue me so much ! I am searching a solution since days, all my source code for those functions is finish. 
I can share more code if needed. Help please !

I apologize for my english, I am currently practicing , thank you :)

Comment: Is the memory allocated constant across runs ? Is it constant when you change your test program ?

Comment: the location that my function is printing is different after each runs, but the sizes and number of blocks allocated is constant , I mean I always get this 4o 4o 4o ..32o list of blocks. 
I did a test as well with malloc and free calls, my malloc add news blocks without any problem but free segfault because those blocks seems not to have initialized the prev pointer of my structure block ...

Answer (score 0):

By inserting a call to `sleep(30)` into your sample program and running it with the system allocator with `MallocStackLogging=YES` set in the environment, we can use `malloc_history` to see stack traces for the unexpected allocation events:

```
mrowe@apollo:~$ malloc_history test -callTree
malloc_history Report Version:  2.0
Process:         test [16546]
Path:            /Users/mrowe/test
Load Address:    0x10d108000
Identifier:      test
Version:         0
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  bash [15909]

Date/Time:       2018-12-04 23:45:21.610 -0800
Launch Time:     2018-12-04 23:45:20.309 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.14 (18A389)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /Applications/Xcode-10.0.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/malloc_history
Analysis Tool Version:  Xcode 10.0 (10A255)

Physical footprint:         884K
Physical footprint (peak):  884K
----

Call graph:
    157 (13.0K) Thread_114575c1
      157 (13.0K) _dyld_start  (in dyld) + 54  [0x1113a2036]
        157 (13.0K) dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*)  (in dyld) + 1154  [0x1113a24f6]
          157 (13.0K) dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*)  (in dyld) + 6237  [0x1113a878f]
            157 (13.0K) dyld::initializeMainExecutable()  (in dyld) + 199  [0x1113a3774]
              157 (13.0K) ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&)  (in dyld) + 74  [0x1113b42e8]
                157 (13.0K) ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&)  (in dyld) + 134  [0x1113b4254]
                  157 (13.0K) ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&)  (in dyld) + 249  [0x1113b506d]
                    157 (13.0K) ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&)  (in dyld) + 358  [0x1113b50da]
                      157 (13.0K) ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&)  (in dyld) + 40  [0x1113b9ec6]
                        157 (13.0K) ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&)  (in dyld) + 518  [0x1113b9cc8]
                          130 (11.2K) libSystem_initializer  (in libSystem.B.dylib) + 121  [0x7fff62b299c5]
                          + 130 (11.2K) libdispatch_init  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 282  [0x7fff656703a7]
                          +   130 (11.2K) _os_object_init  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff656645c4]
                          +     130 (11.2K) _objc_init  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 116  [0x7fff645d0c34]
                          +       130 (11.2K) _dyld_objc_notify_register  (in libdyld.dylib) + 113  [0x7fff6569e647]
                          +         130 (11.2K) dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*))  (in dyld) + 63  [0x1113a669a]
                          +           130 (11.2K) dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool)  (in dyld) + 1477  [0x1113a6571]
                          +             130 (11.2K) map_images  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 68  [0x7fff645e5279]
                          +               130 (11.2K) map_images_nolock  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 1197  [0x7fff645d1473]
                          +                 116 (7.62K) _read_images  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 2468  [0x7fff645d2c66]
                          +                 ! 50 (3.12K) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 77  [0x7fff645d4511]
                          +                 ! : 50 (3.12K) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          +                 ! :   50 (3.12K) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 ! 50 (3.12K) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 287  [0x7fff645d45e3]
                          +                 ! : 50 (3.12K) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 77  [0x7fff645d4511]
                          +                 ! :   50 (3.12K) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          +                 ! :     50 (3.12K) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 ! 16 (1.38K) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 263  [0x7fff645d45cb]
                          +                 !   8 (896 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 263  [0x7fff645d45cb]
                          +                 !   | 6 (768 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 263  [0x7fff645d45cb]
                          +                 !   | + 5 (704 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 287  [0x7fff645d45e3]
                          +                 !   | + ! 4 (640 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 1398  [0x7fff645d4a3a]
                          +                 !   | + ! : 4 (640 bytes) unattachedCategoriesForClass(objc_class*, bool)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 53  [0x7fff645d5731]
                          +                 !   | + ! :   4 (640 bytes) NXCreateMapTable  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 39  [0x7fff645d3217]
                          +                 !   | + ! :     1 (528 bytes) NXCreateMapTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 285  [0x7fff645d333b]
                          +                 !   | + ! :     | 1 (528 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 !   | + ! :     1 (48 bytes) NXCreateMapTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 214  [0x7fff645d32f4]
                          +                 !   | + ! :     | 1 (48 bytes) NXHashInsert  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 373  [0x7fff645d37d8]
                          +                 !   | + ! :     |   1 (48 bytes) _NXHashRehashToCapacity  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 101  [0x7fff645d385b]
                          +                 !   | + ! :     |     1 (48 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 !   | + ! :     1 (32 bytes) NXCreateMapTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 39  [0x7fff645d3245]
                          +                 !   | + ! :     | 1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 !   | + ! :     1 (32 bytes) NXCreateMapTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 181  [0x7fff645d32d3]
                          +                 !   | + ! :       1 (32 bytes) malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff65860783]
                          +                 !   | + ! :         1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 !   | + ! 1 (64 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 77  [0x7fff645d4511]
                          +                 !   | + !   1 (64 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          +                 !   | + !     1 (64 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 !   | + 1 (64 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 77  [0x7fff645d4511]
                          +                 !   | +   1 (64 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          +                 !   | +     1 (64 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 !   | 1 (64 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 77  [0x7fff645d4511]
                          +                 !   | + 1 (64 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          +                 !   | +   1 (64 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 !   | 1 (64 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 287  [0x7fff645d45e3]
                          +                 !   |   1 (64 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 77  [0x7fff645d4511]
                          +                 !   |     1 (64 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          +                 !   |       1 (64 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 !   4 (256 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 77  [0x7fff645d4511]
                          +                 !   | 4 (256 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          +                 !   |   4 (256 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 !   4 (256 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 287  [0x7fff645d45e3]
                          +                 !     4 (256 bytes) realizeClass(objc_class*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 77  [0x7fff645d4511]
                          +                 !       4 (256 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          +                 !         4 (256 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 1 (2.50K) _read_images  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 1845  [0x7fff645d29f7]
                          +                 ! 1 (2.50K) NXMapInsert  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 285  [0x7fff645d42b5]
                          +                 !   1 (2.50K) _NXMapRehash(_NXMapTable*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 84  [0x7fff645d43fe]
                          +                 !     1 (2.50K) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 1 (736 bytes) _read_images  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 396  [0x7fff645d244e]
                          +                 ! 1 (736 bytes) arc4random_buf  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 37  [0x7fff65723479]
                          +                 !   1 (736 bytes) arc4_init  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 109  [0x7fff6572331d]
                          +                 !     1 (736 bytes) malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff65860783]
                          +                 !       1 (736 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 7 (256 bytes) _read_images  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 505  [0x7fff645d24bb]
                          +                 ! 7 (256 bytes) NXCreateMapTable  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 39  [0x7fff645d3217]
                          +                 !   4 (144 bytes) NXCreateMapTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 79  [0x7fff645d326d]
                          +                 !   : 4 (144 bytes) NXCreateHashTable  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 47  [0x7fff645d3392]
                          +                 !   :   1 (48 bytes) NXCreateHashTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 310  [0x7fff645d34d1]
                          +                 !   :   | 1 (48 bytes) NXHashInsert  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 373  [0x7fff645d37d8]
                          +                 !   :   |   1 (48 bytes) _NXHashRehashToCapacity  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 101  [0x7fff645d385b]
                          +                 !   :   |     1 (48 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 !   :   1 (32 bytes) NXCreateHashTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 39  [0x7fff645d33c2]
                          +                 !   :   | 1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 !   :   1 (32 bytes) NXCreateHashTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 72  [0x7fff645d33e3]
                          +                 !   :   | 1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 !   :   1 (32 bytes) NXCreateHashTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 268  [0x7fff645d34a7]
                          +                 !   :     1 (32 bytes) malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff65860783]
                          +                 !   :       1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 !   1 (48 bytes) NXCreateMapTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 285  [0x7fff645d333b]
                          +                 !   : 1 (48 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 !   1 (32 bytes) NXCreateMapTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 39  [0x7fff645d3245]
                          +                 !   : 1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 !   1 (32 bytes) NXCreateMapTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 181  [0x7fff645d32d3]
                          +                 !     1 (32 bytes) malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff65860783]
                          +                 !       1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 4 (112 bytes) _read_images  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 540  [0x7fff645d24de]
                          +                 ! 4 (112 bytes) NXCreateHashTable  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 47  [0x7fff645d3392]
                          +                 !   1 (32 bytes) NXCreateHashTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 39  [0x7fff645d33c2]
                          +                 !   : 1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 !   1 (32 bytes) NXCreateHashTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 268  [0x7fff645d34a7]
                          +                 !   : 1 (32 bytes) malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff65860783]
                          +                 !   :   1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          +                 !   1 (32 bytes) NXCreateHashTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 310  [0x7fff645d34d1]
                          +                 !   : 1 (32 bytes) NXHashInsert  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 175  [0x7fff645d3712]
                          +                 !   :   1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 !   1 (16 bytes) NXCreateHashTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 402  [0x7fff645d352d]
                          +                 !     1 (16 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          +                 1 (32 bytes) _read_images  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 1711  [0x7fff645d2971]
                          +                   1 (32 bytes) protocols()  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 47  [0x7fff645d3d33]
                          +                     1 (32 bytes) NXCreateMapTable  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 39  [0x7fff645d3217]
                          +                       1 (32 bytes) NXCreateMapTableFromZone  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 39  [0x7fff645d3245]
                          +                         1 (32 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          26 (1.61K) libSystem_initializer  (in libSystem.B.dylib) + 126  [0x7fff62b299ca]
                          + 19 (1.16K) _libxpc_initializer  (in libxpc.dylib) + 983  [0x7fff658daa21]
                          + ! 18 (992 bytes) _xpc_collect_environment  (in libxpc.dylib) + 96  [0x7fff658dafa0]
                          + ! : 12 (656 bytes) xpc_dictionary_set_string  (in libxpc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff658db123]
                          + ! : | 6 (368 bytes) xpc_string_create  (in libxpc.dylib) + 11  [0x7fff658db151]
                          + ! : | + 6 (368 bytes) strdup  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 32  [0x7fff6575867e]
                          + ! : | +   6 (368 bytes) malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff65860783]
                          + ! : | +     6 (368 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          + ! : | 6 (288 bytes) xpc_string_create  (in libxpc.dylib) + 38  [0x7fff658db16c]
                          + ! : |   6 (288 bytes) _xpc_string_create  (in libxpc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff658f5c14]
                          + ! : |     6 (288 bytes) _os_object_alloc_realized  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 35  [0x7fff65664682]
                          + ! : |       6 (288 bytes) class_createInstance  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 83  [0x7fff645d683e]
                          + ! : |         6 (288 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          + ! : |           6 (288 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          + ! : 6 (336 bytes) xpc_dictionary_set_string  (in libxpc.dylib) + 41  [0x7fff658db134]
                          + ! :   6 (336 bytes) _xpc_dictionary_insert  (in libxpc.dylib) + 371  [0x7fff658db3ae]
                          + ! :     6 (336 bytes) _xpc_malloc  (in libxpc.dylib) + 47  [0x7fff658db4f7]
                          + ! :       6 (336 bytes) malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff65860783]
                          + ! :         6 (336 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          + ! 1 (192 bytes) _xpc_collect_environment  (in libxpc.dylib) + 45  [0x7fff658daf6d]
                          + !   1 (192 bytes) xpc_dictionary_create  (in libxpc.dylib) + 40  [0x7fff658db0b5]
                          + !     1 (192 bytes) _os_object_alloc_realized  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 35  [0x7fff65664682]
                          + !       1 (192 bytes) class_createInstance  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 83  [0x7fff645d683e]
                          + !         1 (192 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          + !           1 (192 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          + 1 (192 bytes) _libxpc_initializer  (in libxpc.dylib) + 988  [0x7fff658daa26]
                          + ! 1 (192 bytes) _xpc_collect_images  (in libxpc.dylib) + 65  [0x7fff658db5e0]
                          + !   1 (192 bytes) dyld::registerLoadCallback(void (*)(mach_header const*, char const*, bool))  (in dyld) + 265  [0x1113a58b9]
                          + !     1 (192 bytes) _xpc_dyld_image_callback  (in libxpc.dylib) + 89  [0x7fff658db6bf]
                          + !       1 (192 bytes) xpc_dictionary_create  (in libxpc.dylib) + 40  [0x7fff658db0b5]
                          + !         1 (192 bytes) _os_object_alloc_realized  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 35  [0x7fff65664682]
                          + !           1 (192 bytes) class_createInstance  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 83  [0x7fff645d683e]
                          + !             1 (192 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          + !               1 (192 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          + 2 (112 bytes) _libxpc_initializer  (in libxpc.dylib) + 142  [0x7fff658da6d8]
                          + ! 1 (64 bytes) xpc_array_create  (in libxpc.dylib) + 71  [0x7fff658dac3f]
                          + ! : 1 (64 bytes) _xpc_calloc  (in libxpc.dylib) + 52  [0x7fff658dacb6]
                          + ! :   1 (64 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          + ! :     1 (64 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          + ! 1 (48 bytes) xpc_array_create  (in libxpc.dylib) + 46  [0x7fff658dac26]
                          + !   1 (48 bytes) _os_object_alloc_realized  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 35  [0x7fff65664682]
                          + !     1 (48 bytes) class_createInstance  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 83  [0x7fff645d683e]
                          + !       1 (48 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          + !         1 (48 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          + 3 (96 bytes) _libxpc_initializer  (in libxpc.dylib) + 1139  [0x7fff658daabd]
                          + ! 2 (80 bytes) setenv  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 94  [0x7fff657614d9]
                          + ! : 1 (64 bytes) _owned_ptr_alloc  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 35  [0x7fff65760dfb]
                          + ! : | 1 (64 bytes) malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff65860783]
                          + ! : |   1 (64 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          + ! : 1 (16 bytes) _owned_ptr_alloc  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 17  [0x7fff65760de9]
                          + ! :   1 (16 bytes) malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff65860783]
                          + ! :     1 (16 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          + ! 1 (16 bytes) setenv  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 140  [0x7fff65761507]
                          + !   1 (16 bytes) __setenv_locked  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 625  [0x7fff657610fe]
                          + !     1 (16 bytes) malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 24  [0x7fff65860783]
                          + !       1 (16 bytes) malloc_zone_malloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff6586082b]
                          + 1 (64 bytes) _libxpc_initializer  (in libxpc.dylib) + 978  [0x7fff658daa1c]
                          +   1 (64 bytes) _xpc_create_bootstrap_pipe  (in libxpc.dylib) + 45  [0x7fff658dae82]
                          +     1 (64 bytes) _xpc_pipe_create  (in libxpc.dylib) + 64  [0x7fff658eecd8]
                          +       1 (64 bytes) _os_object_alloc_realized  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 35  [0x7fff65664682]
                          +         1 (64 bytes) class_createInstance  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 83  [0x7fff645d683e]
                          +           1 (64 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                          +             1 (64 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
                          1 (128 bytes) libSystem_initializer  (in libSystem.B.dylib) + 131  [0x7fff62b299cf]
                            1 (128 bytes) _libtrace_init  (in libsystem_trace.dylib) + 250  [0x7fff658bda54]
                              1 (128 bytes) _dispatch_lane_create_with_target  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 373  [0x7fff65669b12]
                                1 (128 bytes) _os_object_alloc_realized  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 35  [0x7fff65664682]
                                  1 (128 bytes) class_createInstance  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 83  [0x7fff645d683e]
                                    1 (128 bytes) calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 30  [0x7fff65862cba]
                                      1 (128 bytes) malloc_zone_calloc  (in libsystem_malloc.dylib) + 139  [0x7fff65862d62]
```

This output makes clear that the allocations are coming from various static initializers in libSystem.